# Cuando hago un select múltiple no me muestra los datos seleccionados en la tabla en django. Si los añade y los edita. Saludos y gracias de antemano

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, djangorestframework, django-urls

Cuando pongo un tipo de dato select multiple lo edita y lo inserta correctamente pero a la hora de mostrarlo me pone trabajadores.Financistas.None

trabajadores es la aplicación, Financistas es la clase del modelo

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.